# How can i get page path in asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

Unable to access Url.ActionContext.View.Path
I have to show on particual Path/View/Action Call

How can i get path in ASP.Net Core MVC
in quick watcher Url.ActionContext.View.Path it shows value but can't use gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found solution for asp.net core MVC
//for View
string viewname= ((object[])((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.UrlHelper)Url).ActionContext.RouteData.Values.Values)[1].ToString();
//for controller
string controllername = ((object[])((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.UrlHelper)Url).ActionContext.RouteData.Values.Values)[0].ToString();